# getting Fatal error: Call to a member function _query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quotes\paginator.php on line 33

Tags: php, mysqli

I read the reference given to me and took help from the code but i am getting fatal error. as above .please take look in my code and tell where i am lagging.
I have two pages. index.php and paginator.php
why i am getting fatal error I cant understand.

index.php

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <?php
    require_once 'Paginator.php';

    $con       = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'pixster', 'quotes' );
    $limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 25;
    $page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;
    $query      = "SELECT table2.col2 AS a,table1.col2 AS b, table1.col1 AS  c, table1.q_url AS d FROM table2, table1 WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col4 ";//  AND table2.friendly_url= '".$authorname."'";

   $Paginator  = new Paginator( $con, $query );

   $results    = $Paginator->getData( $page, $limit );
   ?>
   <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$i']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$row['b']']; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>quotes Pagination</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h1>PHP Pagination</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table- rounded">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="20%">Sr. No</th>
    <th width="20%">Quotes</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$i']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$row['b']']; ?></td>

      </tr>
      <?php endfor; ?></tbody>
      </table>
      <?php echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' ); ?> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

paginator.php

```
      <?php

     class Paginator {

    private $_con;
    private $_limit;
    private $_page;
    private $_query;
    private $_total;


  public function _construct( $con, $query ) 
 {

 $this->_con = $con;
 $this->_query = $query;

 $rs= $this->_con->query( $this->_query );
 $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

 }

 public function getData( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

$this->_limit   = $limit;
$this->_page    = $page;

 if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
    $query      = $this->_query;
 } else {
    $query      = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) *     $this->_limit ) . ", $this->_limit";
  }
  $rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );

    while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $results[]  = $row;
    }

    $result         = new stdClass();
    $result->page   = $this->_page;
    $result->limit  = $this->_limit;
    $result->total  = $this->_total;
    $result->data   = $results;

    return $result;
    }  

  public function createLinks( $links, $list_class ) {
   if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
    return '';
    }

   $last       = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

   $start      = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links :   1;
  $end        = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page +   $links : $last;

  $html       = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

    $class      = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

    if ( $start > 1 ) {
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=1">1</a>  </li>';
     $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
     }

    for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
    $class  = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
    $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit  .     '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
  }

    if ( $end < $last ) {
    $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $last .  '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
   }

 $class      = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
 $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this- >_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

  $html       .= '</ul>';

  return $html;
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. But if you try and write the code you can always ask for help when you get stuck on something.

Comment: `"SELECT some, fields FROM table LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?", intval($_GET['page']) * 10`

Comment: dude please state me any document or any reference for  these please I am stuck in this.please bro help me out..

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve this basic problem with mysql first :)

Limit and Offset will be your friend

Answer (score 0):

Study linke i gave you, if u will have any problems, comeback to this post and i will edit my answer to post you back.

[Here you got all info you need to do that](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)

Problem solving steps:

```
Select all data from given Mysql Table.

Fetch selected data, to get it ready for use.

Throw it into the User Interface with for example loop.

Do Pagination to split your data across X-number of pages.
```

You have to put your function (methods) inside the class, like:

```
class Pagination {

function getData(){
}

}
```

Also construct have two __ not _ :

```
class Pagination {

   // properties go here

   public function __construct()
   {
   }

   public function getData()
   {
   }
}
```

To call a function you have to create new class object:

```
$pagination = new Pagination;
```

Then u can call methods:

```
$pagination->getData();
```

You should first read / watch something about PHP OOP and learn the basics:
[some php oop tutorials](http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/)

Comment: thanks a lot i will try to do thanks a lot enough information you provided..

Comment: try it mate it's not hard and even you will get stuck somewhere people here will gladly help you to overcome it :]

Comment: thanks bro can you check the error please...

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Paginator::getData() in C:\wamp\www\quotes\index.php on line 14

Comment: Check if u have method getData in your class Paginator, and if u want to call it like this u have to made it static.

Comment: ya i have made it you can see  in the code...

Comment: @alp edited, you have to work on you syntax.

Comment: ok i will try as you told. thanks..will get back than

Comment: now i am this  Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quotes\paginator.php on line 33